# CSS: Auto resize of height

Tags: html, css

Is there a way how to auto resize the height of an image using CSS?

I have a menu in left side of the website. Image size is 216 x 504.

The width is okay but the height of the image will be auto resized depends on the monitor screen resolution.

Here's my HTML:

```
<div class="menu-bg">
<img src="image/bg_menu.png" alt=""  />
</div>
```

Here's my css:

```
.menu-bg
{
    position:absolute;
    top:130px;
    left:0px;
    height: auto;
}
```

The `height: auto;` is not working. I already tried to google but the result is always the `height:auto` which is not working.
I'm using Mozilla Firefox as a browser.

Any comments are appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: do you want to take the entire height of wrapping div for your iamge..it would be better if you can make a fiddle

Comment: So the picture should be picture in background or some clickable part of bg? Or why are you using img instead of the background attribute? Btw you really want to have the picture with mutated height? So it will become like 1200px high and still be same width? :(

Comment: @Ms.Nobody...uhm is a background only for Menu... the part for header, menu and footer are different file I'm just calling it in php using the include...so for the menu, the width is still the same the height will be auto adjust depends to the screen resolution

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question/english well. Would like to help but I'm kinda confused could you upload the picture for us so I can try put up a fiddle and let you choose what you want? Would quite help I guess.

Comment: I don't know about CSS, but you could try JavaScript.

Answer (score 3):

`.menu-bg img{
height:auto;
}`
Use this css and try

What you are doing is giving an auto height to the container not to the image.

Comment: @Sharath...Hi thank you for your reply.. I tried it but still not working :(

Answer (score 1):

try this jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var height = $(window).height();
    $('.menu-bg').css('height',height);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

For an element with `position: absolute` you have to define at least a width or height, in `px` or `%`, but a percentage value only if the parent element has a definition for that parameter - auto width will always be 100%, but `auto` for height without a height setting for the parent element  won't  work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use media queries to control the height of the image according to resolution. You would go about using the max-height property.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.menu-bg {
height:100%; /* remove this if it doesn't work at first */
position:absolute;
top:130px;
left:0px;
}

.menu-bg img {
height:auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

did you try this:

```
.menu-bg{
    position:absolute;
    top:130px;
    left:0px;
    height: auto;
    border:2px solid red;

    width:216px;
    max-height:504px;
    height:80%;
}
.menu-bg img{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

the "height:80%" can be adjusted to your needs...;